# Objective-C / Can't access (read) file in "Resources" folder

Tags: objective-c, ios4, file-manager

This is probably a very easy problem to solve but i have  not succeeded. I have copied the file "questions_famquiz_easy_110326.txt" to the resources folder and now want to access (read) it and NSLog it to see that i am able to read it.

The code below is from one of the tests i have done based on examples that i have found on the web.

I am trying to access a txt-file in the Resources folder and fail to do so. I have searched for a solution, tested a lot, but not succeeded.

I am testing with the following code:

```
NSLog(@"\n \n >>>>>>viewDidLoad<<<<<<<<<");

NSError *error;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"questions_famquiz_easy_110326.txt"];

if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/questions_famquiz_easy_110326.txt"]];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}

NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"myString: %@", myString);

NSLog(@"\n \n>>>>>>DONE WITH viewDidLoad<<<<<<<<<");

exit(0);  //====EXIT JUST FOR THE TEST====<<<
```

The above code is located in the first viewController that is started.

The output i get is:

```
>>>>>>viewDidLoad<<<<<<<<<
2011-04-24 21:53:47.825 FamQuiz_R0_1[542:307] myString: (null)
2011-04-24 21:53:51.044 FamQuiz_R0_1[542:307] 
>>>>>>DONE WITH viewDidLoad<<<<<<<<<
```

Could someone nice help me to solve this?

update:

Here is the filePath:

```
2011-04-24 22:38:08.562 FamQuiz_R0_1[637:307] filePath: /var/mobile/Applications/7F5FDB03-0D22-46BC-91BC-4D268EB4BBEB/FamQuiz_R0_1.app/questions_famquiz_easy_110326.txt
```

Here is where i have placed the file:
[image]

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

When i used the above it did not work, when i used the below it worked and printed out the text.

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: try insert a `NSLog()` inside of you if-case (`if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])`) and tell if its executed.

Comment: I did put an NSLog and it is not hit.

Comment: Did you re-check the file at filePath? I guess at the first run it wasn't found, so it creates the empty file. Please output filePath to console

Comment: with your code, you need to store your file there: `FamQuiz_R0_1.app/Documents/questions_famquiz_easy_110326.txt`. Or have a look at McCygnus answer!

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading from the resources folder.  You're trying to read from the document directory.  So getting back nil makes sense since the file doesn't exist there.

Change:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"questions_famquiz_easy_110326.txt"];
```

to:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"questions_famquiz_easy_110326" ofType:@"txt"];
```

and it should work for you.

Comment: I edited the answer, I have the path variable named fullPath instead of filePath. If you copy and pasted my answer, check that the name is correct.  If you had already corrected that, make sure the file is actually in your app bundle.  Open the bundle up in the finder and check it.  The file might not be in the copy build phase.